# integer length in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, properties, integer

Stoopid question time!

I know that in JavaScript you have to convert the integer to a string:

```
var num = 1024;
len = num.toString().length;
console.log(len);
```

My question is this: Why is there no get length property for integers in JavaScript? Is it something that isn't used that often?

Comment: Because 'length' is length in bytes and for strings it have a sense as a usual 'length'. Integers have standard data type length, so there's no need to calculate their 'length'. If you are referring to string representation length of int - it's obvious that you should first convert it to string.

Comment: because if you get the length of any string ,array etc, function will  return  an Integer value,  and by default number  have integer (ie: var value = 1200; console.log(typeof(value)) date type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I don't think providing length properties to number will be helpful. 
The point is the length of strings does not change by changing its representation.

for example you can have a string similar to this:

```
var b = "sometext";
```

and its length property will not change unless you actually change the string itself.

But this is not the case with numbers.

Same number can have multiple representations. E.g.:

```
 var a = 23e-1;
and 
 var b = 2.3;
```

So its clear that same number can have multiple representations
hence, if you have length property with numbers it will have to change with the representation of the number.

Comment: True, the integer value and hence length depends on the base of the number system.

Comment: Maybe not *very* helpful. But, I could use it. While parsing a line of user text; I would use such a feature to tell me how much distance the `parseInt` function used from the source string. Without having to reconvert it back to string just to see. (ie: parsing `x+2464+y*42`)

Answer (score 7):

you must set variable `toString()` first, like this:

```
var num = 1024,
str = num.toString(),
len = str.length;

console.log(len);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find the 'length' of a number using Math.log10(number)

```
var num = 1024;
var len = Math.floor(Math.log10(num))+1;
console.log(len);
```

or if you want to be compatible with older browsers

```
var num = 1024;
var len = Math.log(num) * Math.LOG10E + 1 | 0; 
console.log(len);
```

The `| 0` does the same this as Math.floor.

Comment: Do note that this results in: `-Infinity` when calling it with the number `0`. Also returns `NaN` for negatives

Answer (score 0):

```js
const num = 18.5;
const len = `${num.toString()}`.length;

console.log(len);
```

Comment: You should add explanation.